# Pandas Groupby and sorting columns simultaneously

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe `df`as:

```
  Election Year     Votes   Vote %      Party              Region   
0   2000            42289   29.40   Janata Dal (United)     A
1   2000            27618   19.20   Rashtriya Janata Dal    A
2   2000            20886   14.50   Bahujan Samaj Party     B 
3   2000            17747   12.40   Congress                B
4   2000            14047   19.80   Independent             C
5   2000            17047   10.80   JLS                     C
6   2005            8358    15.80   Janvadi Party           A
7   2005            4428    13.10   Independent             A
8   2005            1647    1.20    Independent             B
9   2005            1610    11.10   Independent             B
10  2005            1334    15.06   Nationalist             C
11  2005            1834    18.06   NJM                     C
12  2010            21114   20.80   Independent             A
13  2010            1042    10.5    Bharatiya Janta Dal     A
14  2010            835     0.60    Independent             B
15  2010            14305   15.50   Independent             B
16  2010            22211   17.70   Congress                C
16  2010            20011   14.70   INC                     C
```

How can I get the list of the regions that has two or more parties getting more than 10% vote % every election year?

I have used the following code to sort "Vote %" in descending order after grouping by "Election year" and "Region" and to then compare the top 2 Vote% every year, but it is giving an error.

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Election Year','Region'])sort_values('Vote %', ascending = False).reset_index()
```

How to correct the error as I want to get the top 2 "Party" of each region in each year after the sorting and then see if they get more than 10% vote every election year?

Desired output:

```
Election Year    Region    Vote %
  2000             A        29.40
  2000             A        19.40
  2000             C        19.80
  2000             C        10.80
  2005             A        15.80
  2005             A        13.10
  2005             C        15.06
  2005             C        18.06
  2010             A        20.80
  2010             A        10.5
  2010             C        17.70
  2010             C        14.70
```

Output contains only regions having more than 10% vote every year and Election year and region name in sorted in ascending order. So, here only Region "A" and "C" will be there in the output.

Comment: You should try to clarify one of your previous two questions that you've asked today before asking what appears to be almost exactly the same question again

Comment: Yes, I have tried to clarify that in the comment section. But I didn't get any response. Therefore, I asked a new question. Really sorry for creating another thread. But you can help me to figure out my issue in this thread.

Comment: As everybody has said in those comments, please please put your expected output in your question. Don't just say I want a list or whatever, really put the **exact** result you want

Comment: I have updated the desired output here. If you can take your time to help me, it will be great for me as I need to solve them urgently. Please consider my request.

Answer (score 1):

First sort values w.r.t "Vote %" using `sort_values()` and then `groupby` "Election Year" and "Region" and finally get top 2 rows using `head(2)`

```
df.sort_values(['Vote %'],ascending=False).groupby(['Election Year','Region']).head(2).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: The first line isn't needed right? There is no `%` inside the column?

Comment: @tomjn Ohh yes, it was a blunder. Thanks for noticing. Answer updated!

Comment: Yes. There is no % inside the column.

Comment: I have updated my question with the desired output. How to get that as the above code is not giving the same?